# How do you get Gunicorn + Flask to serve static files over https?

Tags: python, ssl, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I am using Gunicorn + Flask + Python to develop a Heroku app, and I want to be able to run it locally with foreman. It works fine, but when I switch to use SSL for my site, it is no longer able to find javascript files under /static. How can I make these available under HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use nginx to front-end gunicorn? If so then you can serve static content like javascript via SSL by adding a location block like below to the nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    # other normal ssl stuff you seem to already have working 

    location / {
        root /path/to/your/static/stuff;
        try_files $uri /index.html; # this will match your static content
    }
    location /api {
        # your normal proxy stuff to gunicorn
    }
}
```

And separately, you can serve static content separate from your API over http for efficiency, like below:

```
server { listen 80;  location / { try_files $uri /index.html; } }
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    # other normal ssl stuff you seem to already have working 
    location /api {
        # your normal proxy stuff to gunicorn
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up on this - serving both static content and secure content on the same page will cause most browsers to display some sort of security warning.  Ideally, everything really should be happening under SSL - static content or otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to use Kenneth Reitz's [Flask-SSLify](https://github.com/kennethreitz/flask-sslify) library.